# Unable to load a message catalog 'SimulinkCoderApp:codeperspective'. Please check the file location and format

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to use Simulink coder to generate C code from my models. I installed the add-on (and also the matlab coder one). Matlab coder generate without trouble the code for simple systems, but there's no way I can generate anything with Simulink coder... I tried with an example from simulink (the rtwdemo_secondOrderSystem.slx one), and with very simple systems with 2 blocks, I always have the same type of error :

`Invalid default value for property 'title' in class 'simulinkcoder.internal.CodePerspectiveHelp':
Unable to load a message catalog 'SimulinkCoderApp:codeperspective'. Please check the file location and format.`

I also got: `Unable to load a message catalog 'SimulinkCoderApp:report'` and some others.

I tried to uninstall/re-install simulink coder, change the read only status of the file and some other tricks but I'm still stuck. I have no clue what this `Please check the file location and format` means.

I cannot find any appropriate answer on google either. Can someone help me out please?
I'm running Matlab 2019b on Windows 10.

Thanks for your help,

MD

Answer (score 0):

Please reach out to MathWorks Technical Support, and they should be able to help:
https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html

Comment: So, I contacted MathWorks support, and they answered quick and well: it seemed it came from the app file missing (the whole SimulinkCoderApp one), they sent it to me and it works all right now. Thank you for your advice.